# Storing data for use during streaming

Tags: xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

I am attempting to stream an XML file using XSLT3. It has a number of tags that constitute "reusable" data that will need to be used during the processing of the repeating data (where streaming shines).

```xml
<Root>
    <ReusableData1>
        <ReferenceData id="1">
            <a/>
            <b/>
        </ReferenceData>
        <ReferenceData id="2">
            <a/>
            <b/>
        </ReferenceData>
    </ReusableData1>
    <RepeatingData>
        <RefId>1</RefId>
    </RepeatingData>
    <RepeatingData>
        <RefId>2</RefId>
    </RepeatingData>
 ...
</Root>
```

I cannot just `copy-of` the ReusableData into a variable due to the single downward selection restriction. I imagine accumulators come in to play here, but I can't make sense of them. The examples I see uses maps with primitive types, I need to store at least partial node-sets, as the reference data contains additional elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as

```
<xsl:accumulator name="reusable-data" as="element(ReusableData1)">
  <xsl:accumulator-rule match="ReusableData1" select="." saxon:capture="yes"/>
</xsl:accumulator>
```

and then later

```
<xsl:value-of select="accumulator-after('reusable-data')/ReferenceData[@id='1']/a"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

With Saxon, there is the extension attribute `saxon:capture`, see https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensions/attributes/capture.html, that should help:

> If a large document has a short header section containing metadata,
> you can capture a copy of the header in an accumulator, and the header
> then becomes available throughout the rest of the document processing
> using the accumulator-after() function